# matching a string to a list of tuples

Tags: python, regex, list, tuples, matching

Hi all I have a problem in Python.
I am attempting to make a new list using two returns from previous functions.
I would like to take each element in the element list and check to see if it is the first entry in at least one of the duples.
If it is, append the corresponding number to the 'vector' list.
If the element does not appear in the duple list then I would append a '0'.

Example:
Using these two lists:

```
duple_list=[('C', 1), ('H', 4)]

element_list=['C', 'H', 'N']
```

should return a vector like:

```
[1, 4, 0]
```

my current code returns this instead:

```
[1, 0, 4, 0, 0]
```

current code:

```
for element in element_list:
    for duple in duple_list:
           if element==duple[0]:
              vector.append(duple[1])
              break
          if element!=duple[0]:
              vector.append(0)
return vector
```

I know why my code isn't working, but I don't know which tool I should be using instead/ what I should do differently.

Comment: I don't understand how can you have only 5 numbers in your vector, with the current version of your code. Shouldn't there be 6 numbers ? (2 in duble list * 3 in element list).

Comment: the reason there are only five numbers is because of the 'break'.
It stops the for loop since the if statement was affirmative.
This avoids going over the next if statement.
If the 'break' line was deleted it would instead read:     
`[1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [dict(duple_list).get(e, 0) for e in element_list]
[1, 4, 0]
```

Steps without list comprehension. Create `dict` from list of tuples:

```
>>> duple_dict = dict(duple_list)
>>> duple_dict
{'H': 4, 'C': 1}
```

and check each element from `element_list` for containing in `duple_dict`:

```
>>> vector = []
>>> for element in element_list:
       if element in dict(duple_dict):
           vector.append(duple_dict[element])
       else:
           vector.append(0)

>>> vector
[1, 4, 0]
```